# Assign the index of an element in a vector instead of its value

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to find the position of an element in a vector and then assigning it to a variable but for some reason its not working.

Here I am using `vector.at()` as was used by someone doing the same thing here on this site. However when I use it in my case all its returning is the actual element itself instead of the position.

Here is my loop. It is designed to loop though the vector to find the highest value and assign it to a variable(this woks) `max` and its position to a variable `pos` but this does not work.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= people.size(); ++i) {
    if (people[i] > max) {
        max = people[i];
        pos = people.at(i);
    }
}
```

`people` is my < int > vector.

Comment: Um, the position is, well, `i`.

Comment: Also the loop condition needs  `<` rather than `<=`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop goes out of bounds on the last iteration:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= people.size(); ++i) 
                  ^^
```

It should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < people.size(); ++i)
```

Second, `i` is the position of the largest element, not `people.at(i)`.

Last, `std::max_element` does all of this work for you already:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> people = {5, 6,12, 3, 5, 9};
    auto it = std::max_element(people.begin(), people.end());
    std::cout << "largest element is " << *it << " at people[" << std::distance(people.begin(), it)
    << "]";
}
```

Output:

```
largest element is 12 at people[2]
```

Live example: http://ideone.com/fp0T7i